# How to auto width a form element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Lately i've been through a lot of times on a single situation problem:

**I have a text input element** in a web formulary, **inside a bigger div with defined width**.

Inside that bigger div, **i'll put a span text** like "Name: " and **then i'll put the input**.

**I want the input to auto become as much as wider the space** of the div that **the span is not using.**

The code would be something like this:

```
<div>
    <span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
   width: 200px;
   display: block;
}

span {
   display: inline-block;
   font: 11px 'Lucida Sans', Verdana, Arial;
}

input {
   height: 20px;
   width: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

I've been doing some research, but i seem unable to find a precise solution for this problem.

So far i've been skipping this problem by putting a inline style defining a different width for each element. But if i change the font, size, or whatever, it'll explode.

I don't like to build a fortress wall and leave it full of holes for snipers. That's why i'm looking for help :)

If you guys have any suggestion, solution or workaround way, I'd be glad to know. =D Thanks.

Comment: Being a purely technical issue, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there, it will be automigrated if enough people agree with this and vote to close it here).

Comment: is the name your only label? Can you give that a fixed width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically it's better to use label tags for this purpose:

```
<label>Name:</label>
```

Concerning your question, take a look at the CSS3 flexible box model: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

Or if you prefer a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OubGOxKa5I

At the time of writing, Mozilla and Webkit support this and there is a fallback for other browsers: https://github.com/doctyper/flexie

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not possible with that markup.  Actually the only way to do it is to *shudder* use tables (or display: table-cell, etc but that doesn't work in IE7 or earlier).  It also generally looks better to have all the inputs aligned, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

Change `display: block` to `display: inline` for `input` and I think it should work.

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/KYvzM/

Comment: he wants the input width to be "100% - span width", this won't do it.